# Running python scripts from .sh file not working

Tags: python, docker, shell, gunicorn

I have following shell script script.sh.
Both run_api (Rest api) and run_scheduler are at same path.
The run_api end point is working fine but run_scheduler.py is not executing.

```
#!/bin/bash
exec gunicorn --reload --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 run_api:application
python run_scheduler.py
```

And Following is docker file for image.

```
FROM python:3.8
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN chmod +x script.sh
CMD ["sh", "script.sh"]
```

And
Following is docker run commond

```
docker run -itd --name test  -p 8080:5000 image:latest
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: No error, it does not execute.. if I comment ```exec gunicorn --reload --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 run_api:application```  then I get error ': [Errno 2] No such file or directory.py. And there is no such module in my code.

Comment: Generally if you need two separate processes (a Web server and a scheduler) it's better to run them in two separate containers.  You can use the same image, but provide an alternate command (overrides the Dockerfile `CMD`) after the image name.  Have you tried this?

Comment: it appears there is some problem with your environment setup...

Comment: if I run in separate  containers both work fine.  Even if I run only ```exec gunicorn --reload --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 run_api:application``` and then login into running container, and the run ```python run_scheduler.py ``` it runs fine. The problem comes when both are in a single container.   I am bit confused why this is not possible.

Comment: is this the only way that we should have separate containers for different processes. Since my code is same, I want to avoid any maintenance overhead later on..

Comment: @jpnadas  It worked fine after putting  "&"  between two statements as per your suggestion.  The final script is ```exec gunicorn --reload --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 run_api:application & python run_scheduler.py```. Thanks!

Comment: @RajanSharma I will undelete my answer then, if you could mark it as accepted it would be great for people who run into this in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`gunicorn` is running on the foreground as a blocking process, so it is not letting your shell script go to the next line.

Simply add a `&` to the end and it should run it as a background process, as in

```
#!/bin/bash
exec gunicorn --reload --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 run_api:application &
python run_scheduler.py
```

Comment: Did it work? If so, consider marking the answer as accepted for anyone who finds this in the future.

Comment: getting error :  "not found2: script.sh: 
': [Errno 2] No such file or directory.py "    I think it is coming for ```python run_scheduler.py``` . Not sure,  if I remove this statement, container runs fine.